# How can I print the "name" in this this output? I only want to extract 'edge-star-mini-shv-01-atl3.facebook.com' and print it

Tags: python, python-3.x

python3 scan_script.py

```
{'nmap': {'command_line': 'nmap -oX - -sL 31.13.65.36',
          'scaninfo': {},
          'scanstats': {'downhosts': '1',
                        'elapsed': '0.02',
                        'timestr': 'Sun Oct 11 23:11:37 2020',
                        'totalhosts': '1',
                        'uphosts': '0'}},
 'scan': {'31.13.65.36': {'addresses': {'ipv4': '31.13.65.36'},
                          'hostnames': [{'name': 'edge-star-mini-shv-01-atl3.facebook.com',
                                         'type': 'PTR'}],
                          'status': {'reason': 'user-set', 'state': 'unknown'},
                          'vendor': {}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import json
import re
d='{"nmap": {"command_line": "nmap -oX - -sL 31.13.65.36", "scaninfo": {}, "scanstats": {"timestr": "Sun Oct 11 23:11:37 2020", "elapsed": "0.02", "uphosts": "0", "downhosts": "1", "totalhosts": "1"}}, "scan": {"31.13.65.36": {"hostnames": [{"name": "edge-star-mini-shv-01-atl3.facebook.com", "type": "PTR"}], "addresses": {"ipv4": "31.13.65.36"}, "vendor": {}, "status": {"state": "unknown", "reason": "user-set"}}}}'

x=json.loads(d)`enter code here`
x['scan'][re.search(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', x['nmap']['command_line']).group(0)]['hostnames'][0]['name']
```

Out:

```
'edge-star-mini-shv-01-atl3.facebook.com'
```

Ensure that the json is in correct format.